# Show $\int v \cdot d \gamma = \int v\cdot d \tilde\gamma$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set, $v \in C^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^n)$ a vector field with $\partial_i v_j = \partial_jv_i$ for all $i,j=1,\dots,n$.

Let $\gamma,\tilde\gamma \in C^1([a,b], \Omega)$ be two curves with $\gamma(a) = \tilde\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b) = \tilde\gamma(b)$.

> If $\varphi \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2, \Omega)$ with $\partial_1\partial_2\varphi \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^2, \Omega)$ exists, such that $\varphi(0,t)=\gamma(t)$, $\varphi(1,t) = \tilde\gamma(t)$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ and $\varphi(s,a)=\gamma(a)$, $\varphi(s,b)=\gamma(b)$ for all $s \in [0,1]$, then

$$ \int v \cdot d \gamma = \int v\cdot d \tilde\gamma. $$

An illustration:

[image: graphic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Use [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem). The integral over the region bounded by $\gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}$ vanishes. (Why?)

**Hint 2**: 
$$ \int v \cdot d\gamma = \int_{a}^b \sum_{i} v_i\circ \varphi(0,t) \cdot \partial_t \varphi_i(0,t)~ \mathrm{d}t $$

so

$$ \int v\cdot d\tilde{\gamma} - \int v\cdot d\gamma = \int_{0}^1 \int_a^b \partial_s \left( \sum_{i} v_i\circ \varphi(s,t) \cdot \partial_t \varphi_i(s,t)\right) ~ \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}s $$

You should be able to show (Why?), using $\partial_i v_j = \partial_j v_i$ that the right hand side is equal to

$$ \int_0^1 \int_a^b \partial_t \left( \sum_{j} v_j \circ \varphi(s,t) \cdot \partial_s \varphi_j(s,t)\right) ~ \mathrm{d} t \mathrm{d}s $$

which is equal to

$$ \int_0^1 \sum_{j} v_j\circ\varphi(s,b) \cdot \partial_s\varphi(s,b) ~\mathrm{d}s - \int_0^1 \sum_{j} v_j \circ\varphi(s,a) \cdot \partial_s\varphi(s,a)~\mathrm{d}s$$

This last integral clearly vanishes (Why?)

Comment: We did not cover this theorem yet, it is too advanced. It should be doable with theorems to parameterdependent integrals...

Comment: See edit please.

Comment: I see you are using the definition of parameterdependend integrals and $\varphi(0,t)=\gamma(t)$ in the first equation, but why are you taking $\partial_t$ ? Do you write $\sum_{i} v_i$ to indicate you are working with a vector field, and why do you use $\circ$ instead of $\cdot$ ? I also do not understand the difference of the integrals in your second equation, could you please explain this step (why is there no difference left, why do you take $\partial_s$, why the integral from $0$ to $1$?)

Comment: (1) $\circ$, as always, denotes _composition of functions_; it is quite different from $\cdot$, which means multiplication. (2) the $\partial_t$ factor comes up from the change of variables. (3) the difference of the equation comes up from the fundamental theorem of calculus, applied in the $s$ variable. (4) Think about what the value of $\partial_s\varphi$ is. (5) integrating from $0$ to $1$ because that is the domain on which you defined the parameter $s$.